# Struts2 + Internationalization

Tags: internationalization, struts2

Is it possible that when I use the "getText("keyName"); in action class, I can specify that pick the value from ENGLISH resource bundle ONLY. Because I just want to use this value for logging purposes.

Any thoughts how can I achieve this?

BR
SC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you're looking for with:

```
LocalizedTextUtil.findDefaultText("keyName", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

This is a utility class in XWork (Struts2) that handles localization.

Answer (score 0):

see these examples for struts internationalization [link1](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-i18n-example-1.html),[link2](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-internationalization-example-1.html)
These examples are given using struts1, with some simple modification, you can use them for struts2